# How to display images from firebase into recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My images unable to be displayed, no error but images not showing. pls help how to display these urls in my apps

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

First, store the full uri in your database. It will be something like this:

```
gs://yourdatabasehere.appspot.com/IMG_9837.JPG
```

or

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yourdatabasehere/IMG%29837.JPG?alt=media&token=b6c9153f-7d7c-4b05-a60e-7c7d113733ae
```

In your code, once you retrieve full uri from database, just use Glide or Picasso to display the image:

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(photoUri)  // full uri retrieved from database
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_no_image) //optional
        .error(R.mipmap.ic_no_image) //optional        
        .into(imageView1);
```

Comment: can you show me how to retrieve the full uri? i dont know how to retrieve it since it is in a list with only numbers

Answer (score 1):

To get Full url of image from storage You can do as follow

```
    firebaseStorage.getReference().child("*Your storage path*").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
//Here Your Storage Path is path where you have uploaded your file/image.
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URI for '*File/image*'
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            //handle error
        }
    });
```

as @Ronaldo Zoccaratto de Souza said you can use download uri to show image or save url in database.